# XCode 6.1 iOS 8 keyboard decimal pad is not properly

Tags: keyboard, ios8, uitextfield, xcode6

My iPhone app was normal in xCode 5 and iOS 7. When I updated to xCode 6.1, it was still normal. But after I update iOS 7 to iOS 8 (now xCode 6.1 and iOS 8), the keyboard type DecimalPad of uitextfield is not working property[image]

The decimal button is a half the size it should, and when touch on the "red rectangle", the number "7" is selected. It also warning "Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 1425143906_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default".

I run it on iPhone 5S device.

Is it xCode 6.1 or iOS 8 problem? Any solution to fix? Thank you very much!

Comment: I've been having the same issue and have read that it's a widespread bug. Several reports have been filed to Apple and it should (SHOULD) get fixed in an update. It's very annoying, indeed...

Answer (score -2):

I too had this problem after updating to the latest Xcode.

```
iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard
```

This will fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi Daxesh Nagar, I have got this problem on iPhone 5S device. I have tried your solution but can't fix.

Comment: This fix is valid also for a device?

Comment: he was running this on his iPhone 5s device not the simulator